# MPI_IN_PLACE + MPI_Allgatherv

Tags: c, mpi

How can I perform the below `MPI_Allgatherv` operation using the `MPI_IN_PLACE` (I want to avoid make copies of large arrays, so inplace modification is preferred) instead? Currently, since the operation is not inplace, I have to create an array that is a waste of memory called `gathered_array` and store the results of the `MPI_Allgatherv` operation there. This is not ideal since `gathered_array` could be quite large.
[image]

The code for the above operation is as follows:

```c
// mpiexec -np 3 ./a.out
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define MAX_ELES 100
#define CUR_ELES 6

void print_arr(int arr[], int rank) {
    printf("RANK %d: ", rank);
    for (int i = 0; i < CUR_ELES; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n"); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);

    // init all elements to 0
    int array[MAX_ELES];
    for (int position = 0; position < CUR_ELES; position++)
        array[position] = 0;

    // Determine allgatherv displacements and bounds
    int lower_bound, upper_bound;
    int N = CUR_ELES;
    int P = size;

    int *displs = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    int *recvcounts = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    int *lower_bounds = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    int *upper_bounds = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) { 
        lower_bounds[r] = r*(N/P); 
        upper_bounds[r] = r == P-1 ? N : (r+1)*(N/P) ;
        displs[r] = lower_bounds[r];
        recvcounts[r] = upper_bounds[r] - lower_bounds[r];
    }

    lower_bound = lower_bounds[rank]; // {0, 2, 4}[rank]
    upper_bound = upper_bounds[rank]; // {2, 4, 6}[rank]

    // Initialize the values of the array based on the process rank
    for (int b = lower_bound; b < upper_bound; b++)
        array[b] = rank+1;

    // inspect array on process
    print_arr(array, rank);

    // GATHER
    int gathered_array[MAX_ELES];
    MPI_Allgatherv(
        &array[lower_bound], upper_bound-lower_bound, MPI_INT,
        gathered_array, recvcounts, displs, MPI_INT, comm);

    // inspect gathered array on only one process, though it 
    // it present on all processes
    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("---------\n");
        printf("RANK %d: Gathered\n", rank);
        print_arr(gathered_array, rank);
        printf("---------\n");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MPI_IN_PLACE` for the send buffer; send count and type are ignored. Each process needs to place their contribution in the location that it would have wound up if you had done a non-in-place allgather.

Also note that because your upper bound is not the same on each process you need Allgatherv instead of Allgather.

Comment: So would it just be something similar to  `MPI_Allgather(MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATA_TYPE_NULL, &positions[lower_bound], upper_bound-lower_bound, MPI_INT, comm);`? I have tried this and unfortunately the result is that the `positions` array for rank 0, 1, and 2 respectively is `[1 1 0 0 0 0]`, `[0 0 1 1 0 0]`, and `[0 0 0 0 1 1]`

Comment: Because your upper bound is not the same on each process you need `Allgatherv` instead of `Allgather`. And then each process needs to specify the whole `positions` array, plus an `amounts` array.

Comment: I think the `rcvcounts` is `{4, 4, 4}` since `rcvcounts[p] = (N - N_p)` for `N` total elements and `N_p` elements "handled" in a given process (i.e., `N=6` and `N_p=2`). But what about the displacements? The arr `[0 0 2 2 0 0]` in process 1 needs to receive the elements at indices `0 1` and indices `4 5` from processes 0 and 3, respectively. But how can this information be represented as a displacement array? So the `positions` arr on *all* processes should be `[1 1 2 2 3 3]` after the call to `Allgatherv`, but it's unclear me how to do that

Comment: displacements are the cumulative sums of the amounts.

Comment: Per the OpenMPI documentation: "`recvcount`: Integer array (of length group size) containing the number of elements that are received from each process. `displs`: Integer array (of length group size). Entry i specifies the displacement (relative to recvbuf) at which to place the incoming data from process i." If `displs` is cumsum of `recvcount = {2, 2, 2}` then `displs = {2, 4, 6}` which does not work. Clearly I am misunderstanding something here, or perhaps what I want is unclear. If `recvcount={4,4,4}` and `displs={4, 8, 12}` is not possible because `displ[1]` > `len(arr)`

Comment: If the counts are `2,3,4` the displacements are `0,2,5`.

Comment: That is also incorrect. `MPI_Allgatherv(MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, positions, {2,3,4}, {0, 2, 5}, MPI_DOUBLE, comm);` results in the `positions = {1 1 0 0 0 0}` for all processes.

Comment: Did you put the local contribution in the correct location in `positions`? Btw, "positions" is  strange name for a double precision buffer. Are you sure you are not confusing something?

Comment: I changed the name of the variable to simply `array`. I also wrote what you have suggested into my question, but it still does not solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated my code to support the `MPI_Allgatherv` operation; however, it does not support in-place modification of the `array` on each process using `MPI_IN_PLACE`

Comment: By "does not support" you mean you get an error message? The standard says that it should work.

Comment: I updated my code accordingly. The `MPI_IN_PLACE` works, I made a printing error.

Answer (score 1):

To actually provide code corresponding to @Victor Eijkhout's answer, replacing

```c
MPI_Allgatherv(
        &array[lower_bound], upper_bound-lower_bound, MPI_INT,
        gathered_array, recvcounts, displs, MPI_INT, comm);
```

with

```c
MPI_Allgatherv(
        MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL,
        array, recvcounts, displs, MPI_INT, comm);

print_arr(array, rank);
```

solves the problem.